# Django - Create An Endpoint Which Accepts Multiple Values For A Search Field

Tags: python, django

Full Disclosure:

I am a front-end Javascript developer helping with resolving this internal issue we have:

Our Django backend is currently serving an endpoint with the following signature:

```
*.api/search_field/?category=abc&category=bcd&category=def
```

What I want to know is that is there a way to simplify the above endpoint to something simple as follows:

```
*.api/search_field/?category=abc,bcd,def
```

And how would we do this in Django?

Thanks

UPDATE: Thanks for the guidance. the backend developer was able to implement this, however, we shelved the idea as its not a good practice. We will post our solution on this forum at the earliest.

Comment: Most probably you can. But you should share the view that handles this request for people to point you to right direction :)

Comment: You have a urls.py file where all possible urls are defined with a regex pattern. Each url points to a function (ususally in views.py) which takes different arguments. Please post the relevant url pattern here (and maybe the view) so we can help you out

Comment: Yes, this is possible - the answer depends on your backend. Are you using Django Rest Framework?